# How long does ad lib. sim. last

Tags: theory, sheet-music

I have a piece of (bass guitar) music with some repeats in it, and a direction "last time ad lib. sim.". For how long should this direction remain active? Until the end of the bar? The end of the phrase? Something else?

Comment: Until the fade ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since it states 'last time', it'll be until the piece is no longer audible, either finished with double bar line/pause/fade.

Answer (score 2):

Until something more specific is notated, or the piece ends.